# How to access the props in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class newsList extends React.Component {

    render(){

        return(
            <div>
                {JSON.stringify(this.props.arr)}
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default newsList;
```

In the above code, `arr` is an object coming from another component. I can display the data using `JSON.stringify(this.props.arr.result)`. But as soon as I change it with `JSON.stringify(this.props.arr.result.id)`, I am getting an error says `TypeError: this.props.arr.result is undefined`. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what `props` look like?

Comment: since its a problem with your `arr` object, its better to show the data.

Comment: More likely than not, your `this.props.arr` is `undefined` at some point in your code.

Comment: You are right @Andrew. At the intial stage it intialize as an empty array. Then all the data has been added to the `arr`. It is an object with the data from Google Analytics API.

Comment: @Parth Then `this.props.arr.result.id` is 'one level too deep' if `this.props.arr.result` is undefined, which will cause the error. See if my answer fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `this.props.arr` Array?
If it is, the render function should be

```
render(){
    var ids = this.props.arr.map(e=>(<div>e.result.id</div>))
    return(
        <div>
            {ids}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Yes. It is an array of objects.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost positive that, at some point in time, your `this.props.arr` is `undefined`, but then eventually gets assigned a value. Your initial render will receive a `null` or `undefined`, but if you try and go one step further into a key that doesn't exist, you will throw that error. You can use a boolean to control what gets initially rendered.

Instead of this line of code:

```
{JSON.stringify(this.props.arr)}
```

try this:

```
{this.props.arr ? JSON.stringify(this.props.arr) : null}
```

edit: is your issue with `this.props.arr.result.id`? If so, use this instead

```
{this.props.arr.result ? JSON.stringify(this.props.arr.result.id) : null}
```

Comment: @Parth Always happy to help. If you don't mind, please mark this is the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code instead:

```
class NewsList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.props = props;
    }
    render() {
        return <div>{this.props.arr}</div>;
    }
}
```

A `React.Component`'s `constructor` always receives `props` as it's first parameter.

Comment: using `super(props)` is the most pervasive use. Regardless, this would not be the problem. You can accept props in a React component without explicitly stating a `constructor`

Comment: I am getting an error when I use `this.props = props`. The error says `this is not allowed before super()`.